# A sql query to reorder the numbers of a column to be all odd, or all even

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

Lets say I have a column that has 20 rows (it's more, but the concept will hold true for 20). Right now, the column is uniquely numbered 1-20. I need to figure out a query though that will change that number scheme from sequential, to sequential with just even or odd numbers.

So for example I just need to create a column in a table where it is numbered in even numbers, or odd numbers. So after the update query is run, it would change my column data from 1-20 to 2-40 (even numbers only), or 1-39 (odd numbers only).

I'm sorry if that doesn't make sense, or if you can't think of a reason why I'd need that, but in a strange sort of way, I do need it.

EDIT:

Due to the fact that this doesn't make sense, I'll try and clarify a little more.

I have a column that is currently ordered 1-10

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

I want to execute an update query on the column so that it looks like this:

1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19

or

2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20

Is there an update query that I could run to do that?

Comment: Not making sense to me -- sample data & expected output would really help

Comment: I'm sorry if it doesn't make sense, I updated the question to clarify a little bit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For even numbers:

```
UPDATE YourTable
   SET YourColumn = YourColumn * 2;
```

For odd numbers:

```
UPDATE YourTable
   SET YourColumn = YourColumn * 2 - 1;
```

You can only run into trouble if your DBMS starts checking the column for uniqueness too soon, which is ultimately a flaw in (or limitation of) the DBMS.  That is: while the 'even' update is running, there might be an as-yet-not-updated row containing value 2 as well as an already-updated row containing value 2 (originally 1).  If the DBMS enforces uniqueness at each row, this will fail; but the DBMS is not supposed to do that.

Comment: If `YourColumn` has unique contraint, the UPDATE will fail, right?

Comment: In the case that it is checking uniqueness, you can do it in two steps.  Something like `SET YourColumn = YourColumn * -2` followed by `SET YourColumn = YourColumn * -1`.

Comment: is right, a decent RDBMS should not fail. MySQL would fail though (but the fail can be avoided using the additional "feature" of ORDER BY in the UPDATE).

Answer (score 1):

You can show your rows in any order you prefer.

Ordering rows with even ids first:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id MOD 2
       , id
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Order by is what I was missing. What would I do differently for an update statement? That's really what I'm trying to do is order a column via an update statement

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Please edit your question with samples of data. What you have and what you want as result (shown with SELECT or changed with UPDATE).

Comment: @Stephen J.: You can't impose an order on a column with an update statement. You impose order on a column with an `ORDER BY` clause in a SELECT statement. In the sample data you provided, the existing order and the desired order are the same, even though the values changed.